# populating value from matrix sheet

Tags: excel

I have below matrix

```
    Simple  Medium  Complex
A   18      30      45
B   9       15      30
```

I have two dropdown.

One is A/B

Other is simple/medium/complex.

Is there any formula in excel by which when I choose

- A - simple  then it will show me 18
- A - medium  then it will show me 30
  etc.

Thx.

Comment: You can use MATCH() and INDEX() for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming

- your table starts in A1, with the label "Simple" in cell B1
- dropdown for A/B is in E1
- dropdown for simple/medium/complex is in E2

you can use this formula

```
=Index($B$2:$D$3,match(E1,$A$2:$A$3,0),match(E2,$B$1:$D$1,0))
```